# configuration of entity framework in dependent assembly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem. I want to hide all the logic of access to the database in a separate assembly. However, the first call to the database, application crashes with an error

"An exception of type" System.InvalidOperationException "appeared in EntityFramework.dll, but it was not handled in user code

For more information: For ADO.NET provider with unchangeable name "System.Data.SqlClient" not found provider Entity Framework. Make sure that the supplier is registered in the section "entityFramework" application configuration file. For more information, see. Page http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882. "

All suppliers and conection strings specified in the configuration file of the dependent assembly. In msdn I read that all configurations must be registered in config executable assembly. But in this case it is necessary to pull the EF in the main assembly, which should not be

Actually the question. How to use Ef configuration into dependent assembly?

Comment: By dependent assembly, do you mean a class library (DLL)?  If that's the case, the configuration data (not the logic) should go in the config file of the consuming application.  E.g., your independent assembly is called MyDAL.dll.   Your consuming application is called MyApp.exe.   The configuration settings would go in MyApp.exe.config, and MyDAL.dll would pick them up from there.

Comment: in this case for specify provider I should add reference to Ef into executable application. but  I would like to avoid it

Comment: I mean:
 <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in you link to MSDN, configuration should reside in executable application (web.config, app.config).
Your class library only contains code and when referenced from executable project, only .dll file is copied and used. So even if you fill the config in the class library project's app.config that data isn't used.

In the other hand, the only thing you need to do is to include configuration info in executable config file. You don't need to reference EF there if you don't need it. Think on it as if your own dll would require some configuration to exists in config file, in this case is EF section but could be any other thing.

Your config file should look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    ...
  </configSections>
  ...
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: if I just copy the entity framework section into .config of executable app (without specify reference) that i get error "The requested page is not available because of an incorrect configuration data for the page"

Comment: Remember you need to copy ef config section(inside <configSections>) and full <entityFramework> section. The former let's web.config understand <entityFramework> section, even if you don't have EF references in your executable.

Comment: but now it falls with "Could not load the type of provider Entity Framework "System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer", registered in the application configuration file for ADO.NET provider with unchangeable name "System.Data.SqlClient". Make sure to use the full name of the assembly, and the assembly has been available in the running application. For more information. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882."

Comment: How had you added EF to your project?

Comment: I added it by using NuGet

Comment: In your class library you should have references to EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer. And in your executable project you should have a reference to your class library. With this configuration I have an app up and running